# How to rename a set of files with CMD Win7?

Tags: batch-rename

How to rename a large number of files within subfolders with the command prompt?

The files are currently named like this:

> 25738458-10000
>
> 25738458-20000
>
> 25738458-30000
>
> 25738458-100000
>
> 25738458-110000
>
> 25738458-120000
>
> 25738458-1000000

After renaming file names:

> 25738458-0010000
>
> 25738458-0020000
>
> 25738458-0030000
>
> 25738458-0100000
>
> 25738458-0110000
>
> 25738458-0120000
>
> 25738458-1000000

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this batch file in c:\windows and then open a cmd prompt in the root folder where you wish to rename all the files, and type the batch file name.

Currently it will echo the rename commands to the screen - remove the `echo` command to make it perform the renaming if it looks right.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "pad=0000000"
for /r %%a in (*) do (
   for /f "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
      set "partb=%pad%%%c"
      echo ren "%%a" "%%b-!partb:~-7!"
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: You didn't read my answer.  :)  Remove the `echo` and put the batch file in c:\windows as I described.